# Delay the function invoke and show the class image for 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the given code below which show **9 boxes**, which have values like `digital time`,

There is another class **box002** showing `digits`currosponding to the randomly selected value of nine boxes.

box002 `can be dragged to digital time starting with that digit` then that box get `dissappeared` and portion of image under it will be `visible`,

like wise drag and drop all 9 digits in box002 to currosponding box with digital time and finally the image behind the boxes should appear for `10 seconds` and the a `congradulation effect popups`.

**My problem is im not able to show the image behind the box for 10 seconds,  before 10 seconds another set of digital time loads to boxes.**

How to correct my code? is there a way i can achieve this?

```js
        var timeOut;

        function buildImage() {
            document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
        }

        function changeImage() {
            index++;
            if (index >= images.length) {
                index = 0;
            }
            document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + (index + 1) + ')';
        }

        var index = 0;

var timeOut;

function animateCongrat() 
{
  $('.congrats').show();

  clearTimeout(timeOut);
  addBlueBody();

  reset();

  var numberOfStars = 20;

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++) {
    $('.congrats').append('<div class="blob fa fa-star ' + i + '"></div>');
  }

  animateText();
  animateBlobs();

  hideCongratAndBlueBody();
}






function addBlueBody() {
  $('body').addClass('bodyblue');
   $('#container').hide();
   $('#2container').hide();
   $('#3container').hide();
   $('#heading').hide();
   $('.hint').hide();
   
   $('#2').hide();
   $('.level').hide();
   $('.reset').hide();
   $('.quit').hide();
}

function hideCongratAndBlueBody() {
  timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
                $('.congrats').hide();
                $('body').removeClass('bodyblue');
    $('#container').show();
    $('#2container').show();
    $('#3container').show();
    $('#heading').show();
    $('.hint').show();
    
    $('#2').show();
    $('.level').show();
    $('.reset').show();
    $('.quit').show();
  }, 4000);
}

function reset() {
  $.each($('.blob'), function(i) {
    TweenMax.set($(this), {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      opacity: 1
    });
  });

  TweenMax.set($('h1'), {
    scale: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    rotation: 0
  });
}

function animateText() {
  TweenMax.from($('h1'), 0.8, {
    scale: 0.4,
    opacity: 0,
    rotation: 15,
    ease: Back.easeOut.config(4),
  });
}

function animateBlobs() {

  var xSeed = _.random(350, 380);
  var ySeed = _.random(120, 170);

  $.each($('.blob'), function(i) {
    var $blob = $(this);
    var speed = _.random(1, 5);
    var rotation = _.random(5, 100);
    var scale = _.random(0.8, 1.5);
    var x = _.random(-xSeed, xSeed);
    var y = _.random(-ySeed, ySeed);

    TweenMax.to($blob, speed, {
      x: x,
      y: y,
      ease: Power1.easeOut,
      opacity: 0,
      rotation: rotation,
      scale: scale,
      onStartParams: [$blob],
      onStart: function($element) {
        $element.css('display', 'block');
      },
      onCompleteParams: [$blob],
      onComplete: function($element) {
        $element.css('display', 'none');
      }
    });
  });
}

 var i = 0;
 function store() {
  var level = ['https://via.placeholder.com/300.png?text=Level+ 1','https://via.placeholder.com/300.png?text=Level+ 2','https://via.placeholder.com/300.png?text=Level+1']
  document.querySelector("#levelimage").src=level[i++];
  if (i>level.length-1)i=0;
}

function windowClose() {
window.open('','_parent','');
window.close();
}

var items = [  
      { label: '01:40', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1'  },
      { label: '02:20', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2'  },
      { label: '03:50', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3'  },
      { label: '04:45', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4'  },
      { label: '05:35', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5'  },
      { label: '06:10', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6'  },
      { label: '07:15', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7'  },
      { label: '08:10', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8'  },
      { label: '09:30', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9'  },
   { label: '10:40', url:'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=10' },
      { label: '11:25', url:'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=11' },
      { label: '12:50', url:'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=12' }];

var tempimages = [];
var array2=[];
array2 = items.slice(); 

var backimgcount=1;
var len=array2.length;

var item;
var displaycounter=0;


   

var images = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random','https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random','pokedex3d_pro_art_1.jpg','https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random','https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random' ];
var index = 0;

function buildImage() {
    document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+images[index]+')';
}

function changeImage() {
    index++;
  if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
    document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
}
  





function rvalue() {
 
 
 elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor="   #79ff4d";
  //elements[i].borderRadius = "2px";
  elements[i].style.border = "2px solid #000066";
  //object.style.borderRadius = "1-4 length|% / 1-4 length|%|initial|inherit"
 
    } 
 
ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');







for (var index = 0; index <9; index++) 
     {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length)
      
      item = array2[randomIndex];
  
   ptags[index].style.visibility = "visible";
      ptags[index].textContent = item.label;
      tempimages.push({data:item, index: randomIndex});
   
   ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;
    }
  
 var tlen=tempimages.length;
   

 
}
 

function displayAllImages() 
{
  if (displaycounter==0 && tempimages.length == 0) 
  {
    rvalue();
 
 store();
 //return;
 
  }
  else{
  setTimeout(rvalue, 11000)

  
  }
   //tempimages = tempimages.concat(tempimages.splice(0,2));
 //item = tempimages.splice(0, 1);
 
 function shuffle(array) {
   var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

// Used like so
var arr = tempimages;
arr = shuffle(arr);

 
 
 item = arr.shift(); 
    image = document.getElementById('slide');
    image.src = item.data.url;
    image.dataset.itemIndex = item.index;
 
   
};

$(function() {
   
  displayAllImages(); 
  
}); 

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id).classList.add('dashed');
}

function drop(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();


 var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
 var el = document.getElementById(data);
 //alert(data);
 //alert(el);
 
 var x=document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemIndex;

 var y = ev.target.dataset.itemIndex;

 //alert("x=>" + x + " y=>" + y);
  
 if(x==y)
  {
  //el.parentNode.removeChild; 
  
  
  ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; 
  ev.currentTarget.style.border = 'initial';

  var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
  //ev.currentTarget.removeChild(pParagraph);
  pParagraph.style.visibility = "hidden";
  
  item=this.item;
  var arrayvalue=item.dataindex;
  array2.splice(arrayvalue,1);
  
  
 

 
  

  //alert("sucessfull");
  if (tempimages.length == 0) 
  {
 
 displaycounter++;
 store();
 setTimeout(animateCongrat, 3000)
 


 
 changeImage();
  }
  displayAllImages();
   
   
  }
  else{
  playAudio2();
  alert("WRONG TIME PLACED");
  }

}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Sigmar One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Sigmar One Regular'), local('SigmarOne-Regular'), url(https: //fonts.gstatic.com/s/sigmarone/v8/co3DmWZ8kjZuErj9Ta3do6Tpow.ttf) format('truetype');
}

@import url(https: //fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sigmar+One);
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dashed {
 border: 2px dashed #999 !important;
}
.bodyblue {
  background: #3da1d1;
  color: #fff;
}

.congrats {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  width: 550px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
 /* position: absolute;
  top: 0; */
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}



.blob {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  color: #ffcc00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 45%;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: none;
}


.timetaken {
  margin-top: 50%;
}

.heading{
margin-left:20%;
margin-right:20%;
margin-top:-2%;
}


.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  background-color: #99ffff;
}

.box {
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  cursor:pointer;
}

.box002 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27.5vh;
  left: 73.3vw;
  
  cursor:pointer;
     }
 
 .box002 img {
  width: 13.5vw;
  height: 22.5vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
}  
.level{
  position: absolute;
  top: 81.3vh;
  left: 62.3vw;
  
  cursor:pointer;}
  
.level img{
 width: 9.3vw;
  height: 15.5vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
 }  
.reset{
 position: absolute;
  top: 81.9vh;
  left: 77.3vw;
  
  cursor:pointer;}

.reset img{
 width: 8.3vw;
  height: 14.5vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
 } 
.quit{position: absolute;
  top: 82.3vh;
  left: 90.3vw;
  
  cursor:pointer;}
.quit img{
 width: 7.3vw;
  height: 12.5vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
 }  
  

#timer{
font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
margin-top:-20%;
margin-left:120%;
}


#heading{
font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
color:#F534BB;
}

#container {
    white-space:nowrap;
 border:px solid #CC0000;
 
}

.containerr{
 border:px solid #FF3399;
 } 
.pic{
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 } 
 
.container2 {
  width: 35vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 43.5vh;
  left: 13vw;
}
.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}
p{
font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
font-size:30px;

 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                 0px -5px 35px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);

color: #005ce6;
text-align: center;
} 

.text {
    padding: 20px;
    margin:7 px;
    margin-top:10px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}

body{

    background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}

.next{
margin-right:50%;
margin-left:50%;
margin-bottom:10%;
float:right;
}

ul{
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}
  
.reset img:hover {opacity: 1}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore-min.js'></script>
<body onload="buildImage();">
<div class="congrats">
  
  <h1>Congratulations!</h1>
  <h1 style="color:#66FFFF; font-size:24px;">Time Taken:<h1 style="float:left; color:#33FFCC; font-size:24px; padding-top:-30%;" id="timetaken"></h1>      
  </h1>
  
  </div>


    
    <h4 id="timer" style="color:#ffc34d; font-size:29px"> Time   <span id="countdowntimer">0 </span></h4>
    
 
 
<div class="container2">
    <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content" >
            <div id="container">
            
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12"><p name="values"></p></div>
            </div>
             <div id="2container">
            
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12"><p name="values"></p></div>
            </div>
             <div id="3container">
            
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12"><p name="values"></p></div>
            </div>
                   
      </div>      
          
            
  </div>

</div>
    
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
 <img src=""  draggable="true" id="slide"  border="rounded"/>
</div> 


<div class="level" >
<img src="" id="levelimage"/>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: As also suggested in the comments to this [nearly identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929608/show-a-class-image-for-10-seconds), please use a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example ([MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). It's a useful process for debugging and makes it easier for people volunteering time to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have more issues with your code than just what you've mentioned. Essentially I've assigned your 11 second timer to a variable and called it when you "displayallimages" and cleared the interval when they've matched the value correctly, thus the timer won't run and reset the timer to 11 seconds after that.

My edits on line 213, 214 and 242 of the js file.

```js
var timeOut;

function buildImage() {
 document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
}

function changeImage() {
 index++;
 if (index >= images.length) {
  index = 0;
 }
 document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + (index + 1) + ')';
}
var index = 0;
var timeOut;

function animateCongrat() {
 $('.congrats').show();
 clearTimeout(timeOut);
 addBlueBody();
 reset();
 var numberOfStars = 20;
 for (var i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++) {
  $('.congrats').append('<div class="blob fa fa-star ' + i + '"></div>');
 }
 animateText();
 animateBlobs();
 hideCongratAndBlueBody();
}

function addBlueBody() {
 $('body').addClass('bodyblue');
 $('#container').hide();
 $('#2container').hide();
 $('#3container').hide();
 $('#heading').hide();
 $('.hint').hide();
 $('#2').hide();
 $('.level').hide();
 $('.reset').hide();
 $('.quit').hide();
}

function hideCongratAndBlueBody() {
 timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
  $('.congrats').hide();
  $('body').removeClass('bodyblue');
  $('#container').show();
  $('#2container').show();
  $('#3container').show();
  $('#heading').show();
  $('.hint').show();
  $('#2').show();
  $('.level').show();
  $('.reset').show();
  $('.quit').show();
 }, 4000);
}

function reset() {
 $.each($('.blob'), function(i) {
  TweenMax.set($(this), {
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   opacity: 1
  });
 });
 TweenMax.set($('h1'), {
  scale: 1,
  opacity: 1,
  rotation: 0
 });
}

function animateText() {
 TweenMax.from($('h1'), 0.8, {
  scale: 0.4,
  opacity: 0,
  rotation: 15,
  ease: Back.easeOut.config(4),
 });
}

function animateBlobs() {
 var xSeed = _.random(350, 380);
 var ySeed = _.random(120, 170);
 $.each($('.blob'), function(i) {
  var $blob = $(this);
  var speed = _.random(1, 5);
  var rotation = _.random(5, 100);
  var scale = _.random(0.8, 1.5);
  var x = _.random(-xSeed, xSeed);
  var y = _.random(-ySeed, ySeed);
  TweenMax.to($blob, speed, {
   x: x,
   y: y,
   ease: Power1.easeOut,
   opacity: 0,
   rotation: rotation,
   scale: scale,
   onStartParams: [$blob],
   onStart: function($element) {
    $element.css('display', 'block');
   },
   onCompleteParams: [$blob],
   onComplete: function($element) {
    $element.css('display', 'none');
   }
  });
 });
}
var i = 0;

function store() {
 var level = ['https://via.placeholder.com/300.png?text=Level+ 1', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300.png?text=Level+ 2', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300.png?text=Level+1']
 document.querySelector("#levelimage").src = level[i++];
 if (i > level.length - 1) i = 0;
}

function windowClose() {
 window.open('', '_parent', '');
 window.close();
}
var items = [{
 label: '01:40',
 url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1'
}, {
 label: '02:20',
 url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2'
}, {
 label: '03:50',
 url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3'
}, {
 label: '04:45',
 url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4'
}, {
 label: '05:35',
 url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5'
}, {
 label: '06:10',
 url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6'
}, {
 label: '07:15',
 url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7'
}, {
 label: '08:10',
 url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8'
}, {
 label: '09:30',
 url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9'
}, {
 label: '10:40',
 url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=10'
}, {
 label: '11:25',
 url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=11'
}, {
 label: '12:50',
 url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=12'
}];
var tempimages = [];
var array2 = [];
array2 = items.slice();
var backimgcount = 1;
var len = array2.length;
var item;
var displaycounter = 0;
var images = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', 'pokedex3d_pro_art_1.jpg', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'];
var index = 0;

function buildImage() {
 document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
}

function changeImage() {
 index++;
 if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
 document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
}

function rvalue() {
 elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "   #79ff4d";
  //elements[i].borderRadius = "2px";
  elements[i].style.border = "2px solid #000066";
  //object.style.borderRadius = "1-4 length|% / 1-4 length|%|initial|inherit"
 }
 ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
 for (var index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
  randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length)
  item = array2[randomIndex];
  ptags[index].style.visibility = "visible";
  ptags[index].textContent = item.label;
  tempimages.push({
   data: item,
   index: randomIndex
  });
  ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;
 }
 var tlen = tempimages.length;
}

var timer;

function displayAllImages() {
  
 if (displaycounter == 0 && tempimages.length == 0) {
  rvalue();
  store();
  //return;
 } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(rvalue, 11000);
 }
 //tempimages = tempimages.concat(tempimages.splice(0,2));
 //item = tempimages.splice(0, 1);
 function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
   temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
   // Pick a remaining element...
   randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
   currentIndex -= 1;
   // And swap it with the current element.
   temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
   array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
   array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return array;
 }
 // Used like so
 var arr = tempimages;
 arr = shuffle(arr);
 item = arr.shift();
 image = document.getElementById('slide');
 image.src = item.data.url;
 image.dataset.itemIndex = item.index;
};
$(function() {
    timer = setTimeout(rvalue, 11000);
 displayAllImages();
});

function allowDrop(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id).classList.add('dashed');
}

function drop(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
 var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
 var el = document.getElementById(data);
 //alert(data);
 //alert(el);
 var x = document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemIndex;
 var y = ev.target.dataset.itemIndex;
 //alert("x=>" + x + " y=>" + y);
 if (x == y) {
  //el.parentNode.removeChild; 
  ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
  ev.currentTarget.style.border = 'initial';
  var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
  //ev.currentTarget.removeChild(pParagraph);
  pParagraph.style.visibility = "hidden";
  item = this.item;
  var arrayvalue = item.dataindex;
  array2.splice(arrayvalue, 1);
  //alert("sucessfull");
  if (tempimages.length == 0) {
   displaycounter++;
   store();
   setTimeout(animateCongrat, 3000)
   changeImage();
  }
  displayAllImages();
 } else {
  playAudio2();
  alert("WRONG TIME PLACED");
 }
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Sigmar One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Sigmar One Regular'), local('SigmarOne-Regular'), url(https: //fonts.gstatic.com/s/sigmarone/v8/co3DmWZ8kjZuErj9Ta3do6Tpow.ttf) format('truetype');
}

@import url(https: //fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sigmar+One);
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dashed {
 border: 2px dashed #999 !important;
}
.bodyblue {
  background: #3da1d1;
  color: #fff;
}

.congrats {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  width: 550px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
 /* position: absolute;
  top: 0; */
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}



.blob {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  color: #ffcc00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 45%;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: none;
}


.timetaken {
  margin-top: 50%;
}

.heading{
margin-left:20%;
margin-right:20%;
margin-top:-2%;
}


.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  background-color: #99ffff;
}

.box {
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  cursor:pointer;
}

.box002 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27.5vh;
  left: 73.3vw;
  
  cursor:pointer;
     }
 
 .box002 img {
  width: 13.5vw;
  height: 22.5vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
}  
.level{
  position: absolute;
  top: 81.3vh;
  left: 62.3vw;
  
  cursor:pointer;}
  
.level img{
 width: 9.3vw;
  height: 15.5vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
 }  
.reset{
 position: absolute;
  top: 81.9vh;
  left: 77.3vw;
  
  cursor:pointer;}

.reset img{
 width: 8.3vw;
  height: 14.5vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
 } 
.quit{position: absolute;
  top: 82.3vh;
  left: 90.3vw;
  
  cursor:pointer;}
.quit img{
 width: 7.3vw;
  height: 12.5vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
 }  
  

#timer{
font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
margin-top:-20%;
margin-left:120%;
}


#heading{
font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
color:#F534BB;
}

#container {
    white-space:nowrap;
 border:px solid #CC0000;
 
}

.containerr{
 border:px solid #FF3399;
 } 
.pic{
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 } 
 
.container2 {
  width: 35vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 43.5vh;
  left: 13vw;
}
.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}
p{
font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
font-size:30px;

 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                 0px -5px 35px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);

color: #005ce6;
text-align: center;
} 

.text {
    padding: 20px;
    margin:7 px;
    margin-top:10px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}

body{

    background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}

.next{
margin-right:50%;
margin-left:50%;
margin-bottom:10%;
float:right;
}

ul{
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}
  
.reset img:hover {opacity: 1}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore-min.js'></script>
<body onload="buildImage();">
<div class="congrats">
  
  <h1>Congratulations!</h1>
  <h1 style="color:#66FFFF; font-size:24px;">Time Taken:<h1 style="float:left; color:#33FFCC; font-size:24px; padding-top:-30%;" id="timetaken"></h1>      
  </h1>
  
  </div>


    
    <h4 id="timer" style="color:#ffc34d; font-size:29px"> Time   <span id="countdowntimer">0 </span></h4>
    
 
 
<div class="container2">
    <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content" >
            <div id="container">
            
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12"><p name="values"></p></div>
            </div>
             <div id="2container">
            
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12"><p name="values"></p></div>
            </div>
             <div id="3container">
            
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12"><p name="values"></p></div>
            </div>
                   
      </div>      
          
            
  </div>

</div>
    
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
 <img src=""  draggable="true" id="slide"  border="rounded"/>
</div> 


<div class="level" >
<img src="" id="levelimage"/>
</div>
</body>
```